# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Dropdown functionality not working with JScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 and the Datepicker and MaskMoney plugins. My problem is that when I don't reference the above plugins, the bootstrap dropdown Navbar works 100%, but as soon as I have any javascript used in these plugins, the dropdown functionality on the Navbar stops working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My layout file **(_Layout.cshtml)** is as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My Application</title>
    @RenderSection("meta", required: false)
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/customcss")
</head>

<body>
    @Html.Partial("_NavBar")

    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

    <!-- Body container -->
    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Footer container -->
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>&copy; Company Name 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")
</body>
</html>
```

My navigation bar file **(_NavBar.cshtml)** is as follows:-

```
@helper ActiveItem(string actionName, string controllerName, string areaName)
{
    if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() == actionName &&
            ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == controllerName &&
            (ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] == null || ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString() == areaName))
    {
    @:active
    }
}

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <img src="../../Content/images/salogo-01.png" alt=""/>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="@ActiveItem("Index", "Home", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Client <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="@ActiveItem("Index", "Client", null)">@Html.ActionLink("Standing Data", "Index", "Client")</li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Exposure</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Guarantees</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Investments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loans</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Transaction Accounts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Combined View</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My view file **(Client\Index.cshtml)** is as follows:-

```
@using TwitterBootstrap3
@model Px.MVC.BS.Web.Models.Client
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/customcss")

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Client Details</h3>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Surname).LabelText("Surname"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname))
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Forname1).LabelText("Forenames"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Forname1))
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Initials).LabelText("Initials"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Initials))
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.DOB).LabelText("Date of Birth"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Select Date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().Label("Balance").LabelText("Balance Outstanding"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Balance">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            endDate: '+0d'
        });

        $('#Balance').maskMoney({
            allowNegative: true,
            thousands: ',',
            decimal: '.',
        });
    });
</script>
```

As I have bundled all my CSS and JS files, my BundleConfig.cs file is as follows:-

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Px.MVC.BS.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                        "~/Content/datepicker.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/customcss").Include(
                        "~/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
        }
    }
}
```

If I go into Client -> Standing Data, the Client\Index.cshtml view displays correctly, but the dropdown in _Navbar.cs does not expand. If I then go into Home on the menu, the functionality of the dropdown is again available - it is as if it gets reset?

Thanks is advance for helping me out here.

Comment: did you see any script errors in browser console? F12 in chrome or in IE.

Comment: As far as I can see there are no script errors.

Comment: Problem solved. Unfortunately as I do not have enough points I am unable to post the answer here for 24 hours. I will post in the next few days. The problem lay in the order of the .js files within view Client\Index.cshtml and BundleConfig.cs

Comment: cool. please answer your question, so that it may help someone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the order of the .js files in Client\Index.cshtml as follows:-

```
@using TwitterBootstrap3
@model Px.MVC.BS.Web.Models.Client
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrapcss")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/pluginscss")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/customcss")

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Client Details</h3>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Surname).LabelText("Surname"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname))
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Forname1).LabelText("Forenames"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Forname1))
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.Initials).LabelText("Initials"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.Initials))
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().LabelFor(m => m.DOB).LabelText("Date of Birth"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Select Date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @(Html.Bootstrap().Label("Balance").LabelText("Balance Outstanding"))
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Balance">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
@Html.Partial("_ClientTab")

<!-- JavaScript -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/pluginsjs")

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            endDate: '+0d'
        });

        $('#Balance').maskMoney({
            allowNegative: true,
            thousands: ',',
            decimal: '.',
        });
    });
</script>
```

As well as changing BundleConfig.cs as follows:-

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Px.MVC.BS.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss").Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/pluginsjs").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.maskMoney.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/pluginscss").Include(
                        "~/Content/datepicker.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/customcss").Include(
                        "~/Content/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
        }
    }
}
```

I have found that the order of both .css and .js files included in your page is very important.
I hope this helps others.